# How to change a string into a variable name in ruby, Towers of Hanoi

Tags: ruby, methods

Essentially my question is how would I go about changing an input from the gets method into a reference to one of the array names so that I may easily call the move method using the two arrays given when prompted? I.E move (input1, input2). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
first = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
second = []
third = []

puts "Lets play a game! \n There are 3 towers and you must move all the disks to the third tower, however you cannot put a larger disk on top of a smaller one and can only move the top disk from a stack at any time!You can refer to the towers as first second and third."
def move(arr1, arr2)
    if arr1.last > arr2.last
        puts "Hey you cant do that!"
    else
        arr2 << arr1.pop
    end
end

until third_tower.length == 6
    puts "From which tower would you like to select a disk?"
    input1 = gets.chomp
    puts "where would you like to move it?"
    input2 = gets.chomp
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be tempted to use `eval`, but as you probably already know, *eval is evil*.

Furthermore, you would tightly couple the user facing interface to your implementation. What if you're going to change the variable names later?

I would use a `case` statement instead:

```
array = case gets.chomp
        when 'first' then first
        when 'second' then second
        when 'third' then third
        end
```

this would also allow you to accept other identifiers, e.g.:

```
array = case gets.chomp
        when 'first', '1st', '1' then first
        when 'second', '2nd', '2' then second
        when 'third', '3rd', '3' then third
        end
```

Since you need this two times, it would be a good idea to extract this as a method.

Answer (score 0):

One way of capturing the array in one line, you can just type the numbers  space separated (something like "1 2 3 4"):

```
puts "Enter a list of numbers separated by space that will be collected and saved in an array:"
list = gets
array_1 = list.split.map(&:to_i)
puts "array_1 is: #{array_1.inspect}"
```

Generates output:

```
Enter a list of numbers separated by space that will be collected and saved in an array:
1 2 3 4 5 6
array_1 is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```